# how to update field using visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a search box, after I search, email will be displayed in apex:input. so i can update the email. the problem is, when i edit the email, and click register button, the email is not updated but returned null.

> VFP

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" id="results" columns="1">
         <apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="res">

             <apex:outputText  value="{!res.name}"></apex:outputText>
             <apex:outputText  value="{!res.Phone}"></apex:outputText>
             <apex:inputtext   id="registeredEmail" value="{!res.Email}"/>

        </apex:repeat>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

> Controller

```
 public class empRegController {

   String searchEmpNo;
   String newEmail {get;set;}
   String searchEmpSSSNo;
   List<Contact> results;


   public String getSearchEmpNo() {
      return searchEmpNo;
   }
   public String getSearchEmpSSSNo() {
      return searchEmpSSSNo;
   }


   public empRegController(){
   }
   public void setSearchEmpNo(String s) {
      searchEmpNo = s;
   }
   public void setSearchEmpSSSNo(String sss) {
      searchEmpSSSNo = sss;
   }



   public List<Contact> getResults() {
      return results;
   }

//SEARCH EMP DETAILS
   public PageReference doSearch() {

   results =  [Select name, Employee_No__c, Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Employee_No__c =:searchEmpNo AND SSS_No__c =:searchEmpSSSNo ];

      return null;
   }


  public PageReference doRegister() {
  for(Contact cont1 : [Select Id, name, Employee_No__c, ESS_User__c,Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Employee_No__c =:searchEmpNo AND SSS_No__c =:searchEmpSSSNo ]){
  cont1.ESS_User__c = true;
  //cont1.Email = emailadd;
  update cont1;
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please check your Registered Email to set your ESS Password'));
  }

   return null;
   }
 //CLEAR DETAILS  
   public PageReference doClear() {
   searchEmpNo=null;
   searchEmpSSSNo=null;
   return null;


   }



}
```

Comment: From where you are getting value in Email variable in this line - cont1.Email = Email; ?? You should  put more info in the question, like how doRegister is called etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email address in the `results` list will be automatically updated with the values from the Visualforce. So you should either directly `update results;` in your `doRegister` method (this is the simplest approach) or if you have a strong reason to requery in that method, copy the email addresses from `results` into the matching (by ID) newly queried Contacts.

Comment: the email in salesforce is not updated, it only became null

Comment: @gelay If you add `System.debug('results=' + results);` as the very first line of `doRegister` I believe you will see the modified email values in that list.

Comment: okay ill try....